# Synchronizing external web request from multiple machines

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services, amazon-web-services

I have a tricky problem with a webservice I'm running. I've solved it in a hacky way that does well enough, but I'd like to know if there's something better I could do.

Basically I'm running a Java webservice (in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so across multiple servers). The service returns results from its cache, but if the request's input does not exist in the cache (a SQL Server DB), the service must call an external vendor. This costs money, so I'd like to ensure that this call is not duplicated across multiple machines if they happen to receive the request around the same time (i.e. before the first machine has received the vendor response and written it to the DB).

Currently I'm dealing with this issue by writing a "IsPending = 1" row to my database before making the external call, then updating the row to "IsPending = 0" and filling in the received data once the call returns. Before any machine issues an external call, it checks the DB for a pending row. If one is found, it calls .sleep() repeatedly on the active thread, checking the DB again after each wait (30ms currently). If it waits excessively, it just makes the call for itself (but so far this hasn't really had to happen).

So while this solution mostly works, it is obviously rather complicated and doesn't solve for 100% of cases. As I mentioned before, I'm working in AWS so I have their tools at my disposal. I'd love to know if there's a better way to deal with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: your solution sounds good to me.

Comment: How about using a queue? When an entry does not exist in your local DB, put a request in the queue which will be read by only one process (server) and your other servers always poll the database. Also, may be use Lamda functions + triggers to automatically let your instance know when the queue request is fulfilled and remove polling from whole solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a transaction isolation level of `Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE` on the transaction which you hold while looking up the value from the vendor. Using that would lock the database row and block all selects for that row until you commit your transaction. The database would handle all the waiting for you, and you can handle your exception case as a lock wait timeout SQLException.

Comment: this is the kind of answer I was hoping to get. I'm going to move forward with this. thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can design an orchestration layer in your application that would handle all interactions with external service.

- Requests from multiple machines go through this layer to access information from external service.
- Those requests can be synchronized sequentially such that only one external requests is getting executed while other requests enter wait state.

Further benefit to this approach would be that you have single place to update in case of any changes to external service format or if you decide to replace it completely with another.

Comment: I've considered this, but I feel like this only makes sense if the orchestration layer runs on one single machine. I need to be able to scale my application horizontally during periods of high load, and also maintain a minimum of two machines at every level (so one machine going down doesn't bring down my service).